# only partial print when I use gLabels or Libreoffce using two diferent Laser HP printers (I use Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

My question is how can I workaround to have to print a complete page of labels, for some reason the printer print only the first label of many in a letter size page and also not the complete label at first, if then I ask to print from label 2 to the last label may do just fine, I try using two different HP laserjet printer, one of them is a color printer, using glabels or a libreoffice label template I get same issue. If I ask to print an individual label like 4 of 8 it may print just right or not.
To workaround I deleted the printer when printer is off, shutdown PC then turn on printers first and let Ubuntu find them, also delete HPLIP and install the latest version, also I delete printers.conf under /etc/cups, I have the same problem with previous previous version of Ubuntu too it is not an specific issue in 20.04, I look in the printers setting but I do not find anything that could potentially help me to fix this problem. 
I use the label to put in product that I manufacture and sale, the label may have a small artwork or just a square shape to enclose part of the information on it.
I somebody have an idea of what to do next I appreciate.

Comment: What was your previous version of Ubuntu and the version of gLabels you are using? I have 18.04 LTS and 3.4.0 gLabels which works perfectly well on my HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M281fdw. I could never get LO to work well with labels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use Ubuntu for more than 12 years and I keep up to day the Ubuntu version and all updates, I have gLabels 3.4.1 running on Ubuntu 20.04 now but I have this problem since I started using Libreoffice, I using glabel now to avoid this issue but still the same, What I am missing?

Comment: Without trying your label on my system it is difficult to say.